Auto Shutdown of Laptop Lenovo Legion blue screen windows stopcode
Recently from past 1 week my laptop got shutdown after getting kernel message, windowstop code, blue screen. Start button is on but I do not see any screen after trying all methods shown on lenovo to do F2 to get into bios but unable to login to windows.
I tried restarting, RAM remove and reinsert, Dust Clean, battery remove and reinsert, Lenovo Autorepair diagnostics, windows troubleshooting.  I do not understand what was the issue.  I see heat has been increased but suddenly it stopped and shutdown and cannot restart it.
any suggestions to over come this issue.
